# Simple Ruby math operation code meaning

Tags: ruby

What does the following sign mean in Ruby?

```
**
```

For example:

```
2**5
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It's the exponent operator.  Just try it out; you'll see what it does.

Comment: [Fixnum#**](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A-2A) is a method that takes one argument. You could write `2.**(3) #=> 8`, as you would with all methods that take one argument, but Ruby allows you to write it `2**3 #=> 8`. The latter form is called "syntactic sugar", meaning that it is a special format that Ruby permits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means 2 to the 5th power. It is also similar to splat but using a hash when used as a unary operator in a parameter, introduced in Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

In short, RTFM.

`x ** y` is "`y`-th power of `x`". In some other computer contexts (such as TeX), it is often written as `^`. `2 ** 5` is the fifth power of two (32).

Comment: In APL, `x⋆y` (I understand.)